# Delaying _getch() input

Tags: c++, getch

So I have this piece of code where, I think, I'd need to delay the _getch input to make time for cout to finish. Currently spamming or holding appropriate button collects inputs faster than I can refresh the console and stores them somehow, so after letting go of the button it takes some time to finish refreshing and printing.

I've tried to clear pending couts, however i wasn't able to do that.
I've also tried putting Sleep() before _getch() but that just straight up doesn't work.

### Edit

Any flushing or buffer clearing I could find and understand also didn't work for me hence I'm trying to slow down input gathering.

I would also be interested in a faster way to output huge 2D char arrays or to optimize console updates.

```
while (inp != 27)
{
    if (inp == 72) cordx -= 1; //up
    if (inp == 80) cordx += 1; //down
    if (inp == 75) cordy -= 1; //left
    if (inp == 77) cordy += 1; //right

    //cout of a huge char array, repeated every input 


    inp = _getch();
    coordScreen = { 100, 0 };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, coordScreen);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps take a look at  flush() as something to try

Comment: Unfortunatelly it isn't working for me. Although I should've mantioned that I,ve also tried every flushing and buffer clearing method i could find and understand. Gonna edit that now! Thanks for your input nontheless!

Comment: Something giving more info than can be handled is pretty common. You'll have to decide if you need to process all input that the output can handle or if you can discard "old" (unimportant) info. The Apollo program ([code](https://github.com/chrislgarry/Apollo-11)) came up with a brilliant idea of prioritization. Are you making a game? Is "go left" important if "go right" comes next and your game engine has not yet seen the first command?

Comment: It's more like an experiment, I might turn it into something more someday. It's kinda important to register all inputs, It's just that the `_getch()` command registers way faster than i can realisically output 40x40 piece of a "map" around the "player", resulting in some serius delays during long movement, where you'll need to wait for up to 10 seonds for all the movement to end, which can make movement kinda annoying. If someone would be to not spam or hold the button, but rather click it at a correct pace it will work just fine. So i'd like to have it process as much inputs as possible

Comment: Consider using `_kbhit()`.  Just don't display anything when it returns a non-zero value.

Comment: `_kbhit()` did it. It even made the console update faster somehow! Thank you very much everybody!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everybody's support it's figured out. Making `cout` dependant on `_kbhit()` solved it all, making console skip "frames" in case of excess button mashing, overall making using the program way more enjoyable and unproblematic. Updated code below:

```
if (inp == 72/* && TAB[cordx - 1][cordy] == true*/) cordx -= 1; //up
    if (inp == 80/* && TAB[cordx + 1][cordy] == true*/) cordx += 1; //down
    if (inp == 75/* && TAB[cordx][cordy - 1] == true*/) cordy -= 1; //left
    if (inp == 77/* && TAB[cordx][cordy + 1] == true*/) cordy += 1; //right

    if (_kbhit()==0)
    {
        //cout of a huge char array, repeated every input 
    }
    inp = _getch();
    coordScreen = { 100, 0 };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, coordScreen);
}
```